# Missing OOTB Enterprise Workflow Templates

Tags: workflow, feature, sharepoint-enterprise

I am using a SharePoint 2010 Enterpise server, with the Norwegian language pack installed. The issue that I am having is that some of the standard OOTB workflows (within the Workflow feature) are missing.

These are 'Collect Signatures' and 'Collect Feedback' (in Norwegian). I have created an identical setup on a different server, where the workflow templates show up.

I have checked the /14/- folder for the missing workflow features, and they appear as folders. However, they are not available in the system. Any ideas on how to bring them to life? I have tried to de-activate the feature "Workflow" and re-activate it, without success.

The missing workflow templates are also missing in SPD.

Comment: Are any of the OOTB WorkFlows available?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar sounding issue in the past where the Workflow Features get activated before one of the dependency features gets activated. This dependency creates the Workflow library that holds all SPD Workflows. I can't remember the exact circumstances that caused this, but it had similar symptoms (it was however on a us-EN/1033 site collection)

What this ment was the Workflow feature tried to deploy it's files, and created a folder in SharePoint, rather than using the correct (but non-existant) Workflow Library, in turn meaning SharePoint didn't acknowledge the workflows.

You can check if this is the case by opening the site in SPD, and navigating to `~SiteCollection/_catalogs/wfpub/` in the "All Files" area.

If this is a Document Library, then this isn't the problem. If it's just a folder, delete the folder, deactivate all workflow features, and try reactivating them.